# jQuery hover problems with jQuery ui and show()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some troubles with the code below:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id='one'>
                <h1>
                    Title
                    <a href="#">view all</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id='two'>
                <h1>
                    Title
                    <a href="#">view all</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id='three'>
                <h1>
                    Title
                    <a href="#">view all</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

JavaScript:

```
var selector = $("#one a, #two a, #three a");
selector.each(function() {
    $(this).after("<span class='viewAll'>All</span>").hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

    function mouseIn() {
        span = $(this).next("span");
        console.log(span.length)
        span.show('slide', {direction: 'right'});
    }
    function mouseOut() {
        span = $(this).next("span");
        console.log(span.length)
        span.hide();
    }
});
$("span").css({'float' : 'right', 'margin-right' : '10px'}).hide();
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    background:#e1e1e1;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
a {
    background: url(http://lorempixum.com/15/15/) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    float:right;
}
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ws3w/67/embedded/result/)

When I use hover over the anchor tag the JavaScript should find it with the selector and then target the span after it. Then it should on mouse-over slide the hidden span tag to the left with `.show('slide', {direction: 'right'});`, and on mouse-out hide it.

Now, the problem is that the selection sometimes comes back as empty when I use the line above to show the spam. But if I insted simply use `.show()` there is no problems, it will always return as a span.

I have used added a `console.log(span.length)` line to show that it often returns `0`. And again if I use `.show()` it will always return `1`

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Comment: Betting it's something to do with "this"

Comment: Works fine in latest Chrome. I don't see your issue.

Comment: @JoshLeaves check your console while you quickly hover in and out of the element

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I did it but...I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ws3w/72/

As user828584 said, yes I guess it stems from the use of $(this) in anonymous functions.

Comment: same issue here, you are getting alot of IN0 and OUT0 where 0 is the .length

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the span to consistently go away by passing the span into the handlers directly. I'm not sure why the span is not selectable during the animation.

```
var selector = $("#one a, #two a, #three a");
selector.each(function() {
  var jqSpan = $("<span class='viewAll'>All</span>");
  $(this).after(jqSpan)
    .mouseover({the_span : jqSpan}, mouseIn)
    .mouseout({the_span : jqSpan}, mouseOut);

  function mouseIn(event) {
    event.data.the_span.stop(true, false).show('slide', {direction: 'right'});
  }
  function mouseOut(event) {
    event.data.the_span.stop(true, true).hide();
  }
});
$("span").css({'float' : 'right', 'margin-right' : '10px'}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is because you're using the this keyword without binding it.

In your mousein/out function the this keyword does not refer to the correct object

try with this :

```
$(this).after("<span class='viewAll'>All</span>").hover($.proxy(mouseIn, this), $.proxy(mouseOut, this));
```